# Unable to replace text in a file using perl

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a directory of files on my windows system and want to replace the text of a specific file, `first.txt`, located in `PATH`.
All I want to do is to replace the text in that file.
This is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
opendir (DIR, "D:/PATH/");
while (my $myfile = readdir(DIR)) {
    print "got a file\n";
    print $myfile."\n";
    if($myfile =~ /first/i)
    {   print "found file\n";
        while (my $row = <MYFILE>) 
        {   print $row."\n";
        }
        my $newline;
        my $tempfile;
        my $newfile;
        $newline = "this is replaced";
        $tempfile  = "D:/PATH/temp.txt"
        open ($tmp, '>', $tempfile) or die "** can't  :( **";
        print $tmp "replaced text\n okay??";
        close $tmp;
        copy $tempfile, $myfile;
        unlink  $tempfile;
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
syntax error at renner.pl line 19, near "open "
Global symbol "$tmp" requires explicit package name at renner.pl line 19.
Global symbol "$tmp" requires explicit package name at renner.pl line 20.
Global symbol "$tmp" requires explicit package name at renner.pl line 21.
Execution of renner.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I really can't find what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so many syntax errors!

1. You are missing `;` in the end of the line 19 `$tempfile  = "D:/PATH/temp.txt";`.
2. You did not open `MYFILE` for reading, so you should open it first, then close that file handler

   ```
   open MYFILE, $myfile;
   while (my $row = <MYFILE>){
       print $row."\n";
   }
   close MYFILE;
   ```
3. File handler name should not start with symbol `$`

   `open (tmp, '>$tempfile') or die "** can't  :( **";`
4. Remember to ALWAYS close your file handler when you're done with your file otherwise sometimes your data will not be flushed from the buffer.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the above! But I was still getting an error on these two lines:  `open (TMP, '>$tempfile') or die "can't"; print $tmp "replaced text\n okay??"; `. The error was: `Global symbol "$tmp" requires explicit package name at renner.pl`. It was solved when I did the following: `open (my $tmp, '>$tempfile') or die "can't";`. Which means I could write the filehandler with $.

Comment: Actually it is a good idea to use lexical file handles, as they are closed automatically. But because of 'use strict', the file handle must be declares. So open (my $tmp, '>', $tempfile) or die "** can't  :( **"; would be better.

Comment: Including the reason for the failure (`$!`) would be even better: `open my $tmp, '>', $tempfile or die "can't open $tempfile: $!";`

Comment: (Also, I'm pretty sure the values `readdir` is returning don't include the `D:/PATH/` in them, just the filenames.)